# X-Frame-Options to sameorigin

Tags: 7

My Drupal site is on a subdomain of my old html/php site. So, I am running into problems sharing content from my Drupal site via iFrame.

I looked up solutions that worked for others and the consensus seems to be either edit settings.php

```
$conf['x_frame_options'] = '';
```

Or to use the Securit Kit module to change the X-Frame options to disabled.

I have tried both, cleared the cache and the site with the iFrame is still saying Refused to display https://example.com/entity_iframe/node/1 in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The htaccess file was overriding everything. I installed https://www.drupal.org/project/htaccess and added "Header always unset X-Frame-Options"

That fixed it.